# Remove iPhone header while scrolling in react-native

Tags: react-native

Whenever I scroll through my page with `ScrollView` component iPhone's header is always following my scroll and it looks very weird. Any suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **marginTop** to **ScrollView**

```
<ScrollView style={{marginTop:getStatusBarHeight()}}> 
....
</ScrollView>
```

To get status bar height you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the screen component inside SafeAreaView

```js
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'

const MyScreen = () => {
  return(
    <SafeAreaView>
      {/*your jsx here*/}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```